# setInterval в JS выдаёт повторы.

Tags: setinterval, jquery, get, javascript

```
setInterval(function() {
 $.get('test.php', function(data) {
  $('.test').append(data);
 });
}, 2000);
```

Файл test.php:

```
echo time();
```

В `<div class="test"></div>` могут попадать от 2-х до 4-х одинаковых значений. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@ROOT](/users/4208/root), зачем всё так усложнять, есть же проверенное решение:

```
setTimeout(function loop() {
  $.get('test.php', function(data) {
    $('.test').append(data);
    // условие опционально
    setTimeout(loop, 2000);
  });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) добавьте clearInterval для того,чтобы они не накапливались  (внутри)  
2) оформите посылку get в дополнительную функцию и с помощью дополнительной переменной блокировки,запрещайте вызывать эту функцию, пока не получили успешный ответ от  test.php

Comment: @ROOT, clearInterval же остановит setInterval. И как мне потом снова его запускать?

Comment: @Spectre, оформите, пожалуйста ответом. Помечу, как верный :)

Comment: 1) clearInterval - нужен, чтобы каждый раз не создавать новый интервал, с помощью setTimeout    
2)В случае с кодом @Spectre , без блокирующей переменной у Вас нету возможности обрабатывать ошибку, когда данные придут позже чем через 2 секунды